# Camera and LookAt tags in KML files processed by the iPad's Google Earth

Tags: ios, ipad, google-earth

My iPad app pops the Google Earth app via `UIApplication:openURL:` and passes it a URL of a file to display.  The file displays fine, except for `Camera` and `LookAt` tags.  It seems that the `Camera` tag is totally disregarded, while the `LookAt` is partially processed such that the point of view moves to a point close to the ground, much lower than the `LookAt` specification.

To debug this, I created two KMLs, copied from Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/cameras).  The content is generated by a query on my server.  The query's URL is passed to the Google Earth app from my app.

For comparison, I opened the same data on Google Earth running on a Mac.  It works fine there.

This file is treated as a no-op by GE - it does not move its point of view at all:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <Placemark>
    <Camera>
      <longitude>-122.4783</longitude>
      <latitude>37.8120</latitude>
      <altitude>100</altitude>
      <heading>90</heading>
      <tilt>90</tilt>
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
    </Camera>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

The following *does* move the point of view to the general area, but to a point which is exactly 500 meters above the ground, regardless of the `range` value.

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Machu Picchu, Peru</name>
    <LookAt>
      <longitude>-72.503364</longitude>
      <latitude>-13.209676</latitude>
      <altitude>0</altitude>
      <range>14794.882995</range>
      <tilt>66.768762</tilt>
      <heading>71.131493</heading>
    </LookAt>
    <styleUrl>#msn_icon12</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-72.516244,-13.162806,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark> 
</Document>
</kml>
```

I am using Google Earth 7.0.0.7455 on the iPad.

Any other tag that I passed to the GE app, such as for drawing polygons, works just fine.  I'm only having trouble with `Camera` and `LookAt`.

I wonder if it's my bug, Google's, or both.  If Google's, is there a workaround - any way of setting the camera?

Comment: Perhaps pointing out the obvious, but your first example doesnt have a name/Point in the placemark. It might not be the Camera that is the issue, but the fact its an empty Placemark. ?

Comment: Thanks @barryhunter. I don't think that this is the problem because of two reasons: (1) my original KML has lots of `Placemark`s and still the camera does not work, (2) the KML fragment above, without the `Placemark` work well on a desktop.